# Why isn't this directive template interpolated?

Tags: templates, angularjs, string-interpolation

What am I missing?

```
app.directive('summaryAddress', [function () {

    return {
        scope: {
           address: '=summary-address'
        },
        template: "<h2>Billing Address</h2>" +
            "<span>{{address.flatNumber}}</span>"
    };

}]);
```

The output is just...

> {{address.flatNumber}}

Comment: You are missing a live reproduce scenario using http://plnkr.co/ or similar.

Comment: haha i think he knows his stuff

Comment: ;) The problem seems to be that '=summary-address' refers to the attribute directive. How do you map a scope element to a value assigned to the directive attribute?

Comment: Check console. I bet you have some jus errors. But without plnkr we can't help you

Comment: I just told you where the problem was! The answer is below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope mapping needs to use the normalized camel case name of the attribute and not the form that it appears in the mark up.

```
pobo.directive('summaryAddress', [function () {

    return {
        scope: {
            address: '=summaryAddress'
        },
        template: "<h2>Billing Address</h2>" +
            "<span>{{address.flatNumber}}</span>"
    };

}]);
```